# Нужна ли запятая в это предложении

Tags: пунктуация

"Потребители получают информацию отовсюду и сразу (?) и самого разного характера".

Answer (score 2):

Давайте поставим тире. Два первых обстоятельства (места и времени) будем считать однородными - они обозначают сближенные в данном тексте признаки.  Третий член предложения  (несогласованное определение)  в эту компанию как-то не вписывается и носит  явный присоединительный характер, поэтому ставим  запятую или лучше (выразительнее) тире. А без знака препинания здесь не обойтись – без характерной паузы оно не читается, и никакие правила не помогут.

ОТВЕТ 2. Пожалуй, запятая лучше, чем тире. Присоединительный союз И имеется, поэтому не нужен такой сильный знак, как тире.

Answer (score 1):

Побегала по сайтам, обнаружила похожие проблемы с фразами "Всё и сразу и задёшево", "Хотела бы всё и сразу и качественное"- правда,последняя в разделе "ошибки в построении предложений с однородными членами". Однако запятых там нет. Об этом тоже говорят. Объясняют отсутствие запятых присоединением пары однородных членов (даже фразеологизма)к отдельному члену предложения. Согласна. Насчёт присоединения в нашем примере  - тоже согласна, Ларф убедила, так исчезает неказистость фразы, вроде всё встаёт на место. Я бы даже точку поставила, как при парцелляции.
Потребители получают информацию  отовсюду и сразу.И  самого разного характера . Так что всё-таки это факультативный знак.кому как нравится.

Comment: Чем же тогда, по-вашему, является  И? Если нет однородных членов, то соединение с помощью "И"  - неверно. Как "Вчера и в 5 часов" - разные обстоятельства.

Answer (score 0):

Второй союз "и" имеет здесь присоединительное значение "и притом", поэтому перед ним нужна запятая:"Потребители получают информацию отовсюду и сразу, и самого разного характера"